# How can I build this badge with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a badge to my navbar. It should look like the one in the image below.

[image]

**My current Approach**

I use two divs for this. One above and one below. The lower one should do the rounding.
My approach works not so good and I find it more hacky as good.

**Question**

I wonder if there is a better, cleaner way? Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance, Max

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif; 
}
body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

nav {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white; 
  padding:10px 80px;
  box-sizing: border-box;  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.badge-top {
  background: #ccc; 
  margin-top:-10px;
  height:25px; 
  padding-top:20px; 
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-right:5px;  
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); 
  font-size:0.8rem; 
  font-weight:bold; 
  width:30px; 
  text-align: center;  
}

.badge-bottom {
  background: #ccc; 
  color:#ccc; 
  border-radius:50px; 
  margin-top:-10px;
}

.badge-bottom:after {
  content: '.';
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>logo</div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn nav-btn">SUBMIT</button>    
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="badge-top">123</div>
    <div class="badge-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really no reason for multiple elements. Note that I've put `box-sizing: border-box` on your stylesheet. This makes sizing calculations much easier by including padding, etc. Most layout libraries do this.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

nav {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 80px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.badge {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 26px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>logo</div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn nav-btn">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>

  <div class="badge">
    123
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 4.5rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1.25rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  color: #222;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>420</span>
</div>
```